# Xcode: Send value through target action from for loop

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I've got a list of values coming from a database, which each has it's own unique id.  I want to be able to delete a row from the list using that id.  My issue is, I'm trying to understand how to send a value through the button action to be used in the called function.

For ex:

```
NSString *sId = [_idArray objectAtIndex:i];
_fId = [sId intValue];

[deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteFeed:_fId) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The _fId is the value I'm trying to understand how to send to the function deleteFeed.  I know it must be something simple, but I just can't pin it down when searching Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addTarget has defined set of params and you cannot send custom.

As a workaround you can do below:
Use the following api and set the _fId as TAG to the button:

```
action:@selector(deleteFeed:)
```

i.e.

```
[deleteBtn setTag:_fId]
[deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteFeed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now retrieve the tag from the button from the associated tag to identify the button.

```
- (void) deleteFeed:(UIButton*)sender{
    [self deleteWithTag:sender.tag];
    // Or place opening logic right here
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  This worked great!  Still wish there was a solution to being able to pass a value with the button press, but looks like this is the best workaround for this scenario.

Comment: Well, I thought this was solving my solution, but maybe I'm wrong.  Each time I look at the sender parameter, it says _tag is set to 0.  Is that what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What about subclassing UIButton? This way you'll be able to name the property something appropriate instead of reusing the ambiguous `tag`.

```
@interface ButtonWithData : UIButton
@property (assign) int aValue;
@end

- (void)yourForLoopFunction {
  for (NSString *sId in _idArray) {
    NSString *sId = [_idArray objectAtIndex:i];
    ButtonWithData *deleteBtn = [ButtonWithData buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteBtn.aValue = [sId intValue];
    [deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteFeed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [someView addSubview:deleteBtn];
  }
}
```

This will only work if you create a new button for each array item that you want to delete. Without more code context, I can't create a better example for you to follow, unfortunately.